# Change fckeditor/cftextarea toolbar inline

Tags: coldfusion, fckeditor

I gather cftextarea uses fckeditor so my question is, can I add parameters to cftextarea once the server has loaded the page by clicking a button or perhaps ticking a box?

changing

```
<cftextarea>some field</cftextarea>
```

to

```
<cftextarea html="yes" toolbar="Default" richtext="yes">some field</cftextarea>
```

Or is it possible to change the toolbar inline in fckeditor using a java command?

Comment: I know this is not what you are looking for but I have strong feelings against what you are doing there...I would recommend unshackling your textarea and integrating ckeditor directly.  It is always updated and has the customization you are looking for (plus tons of plugins). cfform loads lots of extra things you don't need all of which can be done directly with javascript/jQuery. Using ckeditor (the real ckeditor) is extremely straightforward and well documented.

Comment: I don't know if it would work, but the first thing I would try would be to give it an id, and try to change the value with javascript.

Comment: @FrankTudor Thanks. We have tried implementing cKeditor before but it is not well documented. If you had any documents or info I will try that again...

Comment: @DanBracuk I have tried this Dan but once coldfusion interprets the text area the html code changes so I'm not sure it will work. Thanks for the suggestion though. I suppose the other option is opening a cfwindow with the full toolbar.

Comment: @user1622420 ok it looks like you are on TinyMCE...That is a good one too.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I have decided this is too hard to accomplish with FCKeditor and I have swapped to TinyMCE as I found more documentation on how to do this.